# How does syslog-ng validate the header?

Tags: regex, syslog, syslog-ng

I am wondering how syslog-ng validates that the header is in the correct format (pri, timestamp, hostname). Does it use regular expressions for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it uses a handwritten parser for this purpose. it's in the syslogformat plugin in 3.3 and was in logmsg.c earlier.